# Building HTree in Processing using Java

Tags: java, processing

I need to build an HTree for an exercise. I am so lost because my teacher's teaching ways is questionable. Anyway what we have to do is make an HTree using recursive methods. I had no idea how to start so I found a method online but when I pasted it, it had some errors. So I managed to remove all the errors (at least the underlined ones). When I run the code, it's just a blank block.

```
void drawH(double x, double y, double size) {

        // compute the coordinates of the 4 tips of the H
        double x0 = x - size/2;
        double x1 = x + size/2;
        double y0 = y - size/2;
        double y1 = y + size/2;

        // draw the 3 line segments of the H
        draw(x0, y0, x0, y1);    
        draw(x1, y0, x1, y1);    
        draw(x0,  y, x1,  y);   
    }

void draw(int n, double x, double y, double size) {
        if (n == 0) return;
        drawH(x, y, size);

        // compute x- and y-coordinates of the 4 half-size H-trees
        double x0 = x - size/2;
        double x1 = x + size/2;
        double y0 = y - size/2;
        double y1 = y + size/2;

        // recursively draw 4 half-size H-trees of order n-1
        draw(n-1, x0, y0, size/2);    // lower left  H-tree
        draw(n-1, x0, y1, size/2);    // upper left  H-tree
        draw(n-1, x1, y0, size/2);    // lower right H-tree
        draw(n-1, x1, y1, size/2);    // upper right H-tree
    }

    // reads an integer command-line argument n and plots an order n H-tree
void main() {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        double x = 0.5, y = 0.5;   // center of H-tree
        double size = 0.5;         // side length of H-tree
        draw(n, x, y, size);
    }
```

Comment: Where is `line` defined?

Comment: Isn't it at the bottom (Second last line)? Also do we need to define in because I thought it was just a function in processing that makes a line.

Comment: No, it is not. You call `line` at the bottom second last line, you are using there a method called `line` that was already defined somewhere.

Comment: Oh, then do I just use draw instead?

Comment: Also my teacher gave us examples in which he used line. I don't see line defined anywhere. Should I send it here? I don't know how pretty it would look though.

Comment: First we need to understand what 1. The code aims to do 2. The code does. At this point none of those are clear to me and I try to figure out what you have and what you want to have. Since you call `line`, there are two possibilities: 1. `line` does not exist. In this case you get an error. 2. `line` exists. In which case you need to find its definition.

Comment: Do you use an IDE, like NetBeans? Usually if you press Ctrl and while doing so hover on `line`, then it provides some information. Can you gather some information about what `line` is? I will have many questions before I lead you to a solution. Because you are a beginner, we need to make small steps towards the solution rather than large steps.

Comment: Yea, this is my first time using processing so I don't know any of these. As I said before, I got this code from a website. I think I might have found the error. When I initially got the code all the line functions were draw. I changed it to line since I saw my teachers examples. Should I change it back to draw right now?

Comment: We can choose to understand what this code does or we can scratch all of it and solve the problem without this code. But, if this code is of any importance, then we need to find out what it does. We need to have a definition of what `line` is.

Comment: As I said before, this was not the original code I got. So I think I should change it back and then try and solve. I added the line "function" since I saw the same on my teachers examples

Comment: The `line(n, x, y, size);` is unclear. You likely have `void line(` somewhere in your code. If you search for this exact term, you may find the definition. This is actually the most important question you need to figure out, because this is the kind of problem you will need to always figure out while you are coding.

Comment: I do not know what code you want to use. Please change your current code to the appropriate one if not already and let me know.

Comment: I changed it to the original one. I think I should try to solve from here.

Comment: Now it's much more clear!

Comment: I'm really sorry about the confusion.

Comment: No worries. So, is this working or not? If not, then how is it not working?

Comment: Alright, so the 3 draws under // draw the 3 line segments of the H are underlined red. They state that The function draw expects parameters like: draw(int, double, double, double).

Comment: @LajosArpad He means Processing's [`line(x1,y1, x2, y2)`](https://processing.org/reference/line_.html).

Comment: I changed it to draw since he said that line is not a function in processing. Should I change it back?

Comment: `x0` and `x1` are double, while `draw` expects `int` as the first parameter.

Comment: Arikakate, I did not say that. I was asking for its definition.

Comment: Try changing `draw(x0, y0, x0, y1);` to `draw((int)x0, y0, x0, y1);`. Is that line still underlined then?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. So should I change it back?

Comment: Arikakate, no, let's solve the issue as it is now.

Comment: Maybe you will need to change it back. It is certainly possible. But let's not jump in an arbitrary way. Let's solve this systematically.

Comment: Alright. I changed it to `draw((int)x0, y0, x0, y1);`. Seems to have removed the underline. I am now applying it to all 3 lines.

Comment: Okay. So, we have solved the type error. I predict that the function will not work properly now either, because you have defined both `draw` and `drawH` and there is no actual drawing there.

Comment: But we have passed our first obstacle successfully.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza successfully found the definition of the `line` method. You will probably need to use it. Note that it expects four `float` parameters, so you might need to convert your `double` parameters to float.

Comment: Yes, when I try to run it, it's just a small empty box. So now we move on to actually making the code draw.

Comment: Yes, we needed to fix the type error first to make sure that we can see anything.

Comment: `drawH` has three calls to `draw`. I think you were right when you assumed that you will need to change those to a call to `line`.

Comment: Alright, so I should change all the draws to line and make the double parameters to float?

Comment: Yes! `draw(x0, y0, x0, y1);` -> `draw((float)x0, (float)y0, (float)x0, (float)y1);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239552/discussion-between-arikakate-and-lajos-arpad).

Comment: Wait, shouldn't it be `line((float)x0, (float)y0, (float)x0, (float)y1);`? Since we are trying to change draw to line. When I do `draw((float)x0, (float)y0, (float)x0, (float)y1);` it still gives me the error.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I've meant `line((float)x0, (float)y0, (float)x0, (float)y1);`. Excuse me for the confusion!

Comment: Yes! I got it to work! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using other people code in my view as long as you:

1. credit the people
2. understand the code you're trying to use
3. optional: have fun hacking/tweaking the code and remixing it with something of your own

There are several issues with your code and unfortunately I won't have the time to review each one in detail, but I will mention a few:

- `main()` isn't called, perhaps you meant to call it from Processing's `setup()` ?
- it's a good idea to check if `args` is not `null` and its length is at least 1 to be able to parse a value for `n`.
- You're accidentally creating infinite recursion loops (which will stackoverflow): `main()` calls `draw()`, `draw()` calls `drawH()`, `drawH()` calls `draw()` several times (which will call `drawH()` which will call `draw()`, and so on).

I'm asuming you're using the [Princeton H-Tree example by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Htree.java.html). If this is the case I'd simply swap `double` to `float` types for easier drawing in Processing:

```java
/*
 * Based on Htree.java demo by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne
 * original URL: https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Htree.java.html
*/
void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  background(255);
  main();
}

void drawH(float x, float y, float size) {

  // compute the coordinates of the 4 tips of the H
  float x0 = x - size/2;
  float x1 = x + size/2;
  float y0 = y - size/2;
  float y1 = y + size/2;

  // draw the 3 line segments of the H
  line(x0, y0, x0, y1);
  line(x1, y0, x1, y1);
  line(x0, y, x1, y);
}

void draw(int n, float x, float y, float size) {
  if (n == 0) return;
  drawH(x, y, size);

  // compute x- and y-coordinates of the 4 half-size H-trees
  float x0 = x - size/2;
  float x1 = x + size/2;
  float y0 = y - size/2;
  float y1 = y + size/2;

  // recursively draw 4 half-size H-trees of order n-1
  draw(n-1, x0, y0, size/2);    // lower left  H-tree
  draw(n-1, x0, y1, size/2);    // upper left  H-tree
  draw(n-1, x1, y0, size/2);    // lower right H-tree
  draw(n-1, x1, y1, size/2);    // upper right H-tree
}

// reads an integer command-line argument n and plots an order n H-tree
void main() {
  // start with a default value
  int n = 6;
  // override that value with args if they exisst (e.g. sketch is launched via command line)
  if(args != null && args.length > 0){
    n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    println("parsed n=", n);
  }
  float x = width * 0.5, y = height * 0.5;   // center of H-tree
  int size = 600;         // side length of H-tree
  draw(n, x, y, size);
}
```

If you want to test the command line arguments you would need to:

- add the folder containing processing-java (it's in the same folder the Processing executable lives) to the `PATH` environment-variable (or alternatively `cd` into that directory as a temporary option)
- run your sketch passing the integer argument: e.g. `processing-java --sketch=path/to/yourHTreeSketch --run 3` (where 3 is the example recursion level)

(Alternatively you can export an application (via *File > Export Application* (`Ctrl+Shift+E / CMD+Shift+E`) and run that from command line passing the int argument)

I wish I had the time to explain recursion: it's such a fun topic!

There are really good resources out there. Check out Daniel Shiffman's:

- [Recursive Tree example](https://processing.org/examples/tree.html) (notice as you move the cursor to the right edge od the sketch it looks like an H-Tree: hopefully this is visually intuitive)
- [Fractal Trees - Recursive Coding Train youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jjeOYMjmDU&ab_channel=TheCodingTrain)

Good luck and have fun!